# Toggle visibility of sibling element jquery

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have several divs on a page. Each div has a heading which I can click to toggle visibility of the corresponding div. The divs are set to `display:none` by default.

I have used `#ids` in the click functions of each of the divs , however since I have several divs on the same page. I would want to use  a single `.class` so that I have a single class thus a single function that controls the visibility.

I am guessing i would then need to use `.parent` and `.sibling` classes to do this.

Below is an excerpt from my code: 
HTML:

```
<div> 
    <legend>
        <a id="show_table" class="show_table" href="#">
            <span id="plus_minus"></span>Div
        </a>
    </legend>
    <div class="toshow" id="toshow">Div to be shown</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#show_table').click(function(){
    $("#toshow").slideToggle(); 
})
```

I would think to make this more efficient, so that I don't have to do this for every div using the `#id`s I would want to know how to use a single `.class` , probably parent and siblings of it to make this.

As an addition, I would like to have a minus/plus sign toggle functionality on the `plus_minus` span. I had the same working using the individual `ids` . How would I be able to achieve this using a single `.class`. I attempted this using below:

```
$('.div_show').click( function(){

$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();

if($(this).parent().next().is(':visible'){

$(this).closest('span').find('plus_minus').text('+');

}

else {

$(this).closest('span').find('plus_minus').text('-');

}


 });
```

However it seems not to work.

Suggestions on how to achieve this +/- toggle functionality appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not try this

```
$('.show_table').click(function(){

    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();

})
```

**UPDATED CODE**

Because you are using SlideToggle the changes to the DOM is not readily updated.. So you have to handle the visibility issues in the callback function of it..

Try this code

```
$('.show_table').click(function(){
      var $elem = $(this);
      $(this).parent().next().slideToggle('slow', function() {
          if($(this).is(':visible')){
             $elem.find('span').html('+');
          }
          else{
             $elem.find('span').html('-');
          }              
      });
})
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/5SCnf/12/)

Comment: Thanks this worked, however i had to remove `<hr/>` after the `legend` as it was the next sibling after legend. Is it possible to pass a variable in the `next()` method like say `next(2)` so it traverses to the 2nd next element?

Comment: You can pass next('div') to select the next div element

Comment: Thanks, will try that. See edited question on plus minus `toggle` functionality.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#show_table').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("div.toshow").slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the `legend` element, and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to get the following sibling (which is your `div`):

```
$(".show_table").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});
```

If your markup is likely to change in structure, you could make this a little more flexible by using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead of `.parent()`, and then using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(".show_table").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("div").find(".toshow").slideToggle();
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/96xqQ/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$('.show_table').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('div').find(".toshow").slideToggle();

}) ;
```

or you can place a class on your container div for title and div like

```
<div class='container'> 
  <legend>
     <a id="show_table" class="show_table" href="#">
       <span id="plus_minus"></span>Div
     </a>
   </legend>

   <div class = "toshow" id = "toshow" >Div to be shown</div>

 </div>
```

Then you can try this

```
$('.show_table').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('.container').find(".toshow").slideToggle();

}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('.show_table').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find('.my-toggle-class').slideToggle(); 
});
```

Comment: This won't work. The parent is the `legend` element and the toggle element is not a descendant of that.